# Conditional Elements within template?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am very new to meteor, so I am unfamiliar with certain aspects of it.

I was wondering it was possible to display certain elements within a sub-template depending on what page/'parent' level template is being displayed.

('parent' template)

```
<template name="aboutPage">
     {{> contactForm }}
</template>
```

contactForm

```
{{#if is aboutPage}}
    <a href="#" class="button">HOME</a>
{{/if}}
```

Something along the line of above. Inside of `contactForm` show the `.button` element only if the page is `aboutPage`. I apologize for the incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [iron:router](https://atmospherejs.com/iron/router) Package.

And you define routes like this.

```
 Router.route('/about', function () {
      this.render('aboutPage');
    });
```

Now every time a user go to `/aboutPage`, all the html inside `<template name="aboutPage">` will show.

Take a look into the [iron:router Guide](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md) on GitHub

Also look [this examples](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/devel/examples) from iron:router.

**Update(based on user comment)**
   Create the helper

```
Template.example.helpers({
  showForm:function(){
     if(validation){
      return true;
    }else{
     return false;
   }
 }
})
```

And we use the helper like this.

```
<template name="example">
    {{#if showForm}}
     <!-- Form here -->
     {{else}}
     <!-- don't show form -->
    {{/if}}
  </template>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already do. I was just wondering if there was a pre-defined way to do what I was hoping. I've done it like this `{{> contactForm foo=true }}`  and then `{{#if foo}} //something {{/if}}` - but was curious if there were other ways to approach.